# How to eval an object creation in javascript

Tags: javascript, eval

I'm doing some exercises from school where is asking me to eval the class creation, I am given the html with several eval scripts. I'm supposed to create the javascript file to generate certain output.

This is the eval one:

```
 try { 
    var output = eval('peter = new Person("Roger Roger")'); 
  } 
  catch (err) { 
    var output = "[JavaScript Error] " + err.message; 
  } 
 if (output != '[Person "Roger Roger"]') { 
    error = true; 
 }
```

the expected output should be:

`[Person "Roger Roger"]`

but I'm getting

`[object Object]`

I've been looking around, but there isn't much information on how to evaluate the class creation.

Your help is very much appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand what purpose `eval()` has in that code. `peter = new Person("Roger Roger")` creates a new object, you don't need to `eval` anything.

Comment: @nnnnnn this is the javascript code inside the html. 

`try {
     var output = "" + eval('peter = new Person("Roger Roger")');
    } catch (err) {
        var output = "[JavaScript Error] " + err.message;
    }
if (output != '[Person "Roger Roger"]') {
    error = true;
}`
from there i need to create the Person class in order to generate the correct output

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add that code there, then show us how you've implemented the `Person()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you coerce `eval`'s return value to a string you get the default `toString` implementation.

You need to create a `Person.prototype.toString` method so coercion returns the output you're looking for, e.g.,

```
Person.prototype.toString = function() {
  return "[Person " + this.name + "]";
}

var output = "" + eval('peter = new Person("Roger Roger")');
console.log(output);
> [Person Roger Roger]
```

OTOH, it's not super-clear to me what the assignment ultimately is.